# How to take what is written on a <textarea> and then replicate it onto a separate html page

Tags: php, html

Hi I was wondering how you could take what is written on a textarea and then replicate it onto a separate html page. Much like what is done here on stack overflow, how something is written, posted and then people can see it.

An example of the text area's and submit button
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MQYL.jpg)

An example of the code (for the textarea)

```
<form class="pryform" form action="phpfile.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName1">Name (optional, will be displayed)</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="prnform" placeholder="Name" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputDescription1">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="prdform" placeholder="Description" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="button" data-text-loading="Loading...">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then an example of what should occur:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBaCZ.gif)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a 'blogging' website where you can post stuffs?

Comment: The same way you do with any other input field

Comment: It works like other input tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. form page:

```
<form method="get" class="pryform" form action="phpfile.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Name (optional, will be displayed)</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="exampleInputName1" id="prnform" placeholder="Name" rows="1"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputDescription1">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="exampleInputDescription1" id="prdform" placeholder="Description" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="submit" data-text-loading="Loading...">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the phpfile.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
  echo $_GET['exampleInputName1'] . "<br />";
  echo $_GET['exampleInputDescription1'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `name` for your textarea. For example:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="prnform" placeholder="Name" rows="1" name="name"></textarea>
```

and

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="prdform" placeholder="Description" rows="3" name="description"></textarea>
```

Then you can access them in `phpfile.php` as `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['description']`

```
<h2><?= $_GET['name'] ?></h2>
<h1><?= $_GET['description'] ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

html code:-

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="text" placeholder="enter the text here..."></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="click here">
</form>
```

php code:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
echo $_POST["text"];
}
?>
```